# Using javascript instead Iframe source?

Tags: javascript, iframe, embed, src

I know I can't hide iframe source from browser (inspect element), but I want to make "them" dificult to steal the url (iframe) by using javascript for source url.

If I have:

```
<iframe width="420" height="315" src="//www.youtube.com/embed/xxxxxxx" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

Can I change `//www.youtube.com/embed/xxxxxxx` with javascript?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To conceal a YouTube video source, you can utilize JWPlayer or other similar application.  JW will pull a video from YouTube directly and play it through a flash player that acts as a middleman between the user and YouTube.

http://www.jwplayer.com/about-jwplayer/

Think about it like they're in a focus group and watching the video but they don't get to meet the people behind the glass.

For a demonstration, visit http://www.wimp.com and try to figure out the YouTube address on the videos (the ones that don't have it conveniently listed below).

Answer (score 0):

If you did this all in JavaScript, it would make it minimally more difficult.

HTML:

```
<iframe id="myFrame" width="420" height="315" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

In a separate JS file:

```
document.getElementById("myFrame").src = "//www.youtube.com/embed/xxxxxxx";
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you are looking for dude :) This node.js plugin can protect your script as much as possible. Also the creator wrote that this is a ongoing project so I think he will added some great features in the future aswell

`<script data-wchIyvpKUkArTeyUIZsCekKZRROZZzMNErjvtdIqWGkytjDyhJ="bCCnkxHMRCbEnVtvOWxOqBtKgsYkZEmWzPKybVKvJktkXTWDnc" type="text/javascript"></script>`

https://www.npmjs.com/package/location-hide

Answer (score -1):

why not?
iframe.src = 'url you need';

Comment: It is easy to copy. I searched to hide src in iframe, but it is not possible, so I want at least change src with an javascript.

Comment: the props in JS are bound to attributes in the elements. so if you change src wia JS this will immediately reflect on the element

Comment: you can try using your server as a 'proxy' for a links. point the SRC to an action on your server and then write content to response. but not sure this will help with iframe

Comment: If you know another way of making it harder to see the iframe source, than suggest it. If I upload video to youtube and make it private, embed on my site, they spread it easily by inspecting element and copy html.

Comment: another thing i can suggest is to use video players, not iframes. they sometimes work with a canvas so src wont be accessible so easy